# How do I store Utc timestamp in postgres by default?

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime, timezone, utc

I know there was a similar question posted, but it is 5 years old.

I'm creating a table in postgres with a field `created_at` defined like this:

```
created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT (now() at time zone('utc'))
```

For some reason actual datetime value stored in the database has local timezone offset.

How do I make postgres store a timestamp with an actual Utc offset? Thank you

Comment: You want that to be `created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()`. The entered time will automatically rotated to `UTC` from the database `show timezone;` setting for storage. It will then be rotated back to the `timezone` on display.

Answer (score 0):

My code from the question worked as well. The issue was kind of stupid: I'm using DBeaver to inspect my database and apparently DBeaver converts UTC time into local time when it displayed to the user.

Comment: See my comment on your question, that rotation is actually probably being done by the database.